# Why is it adding $1$ to both sides of the equation $Tn = 2T_{n-1} + 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I found an old book in my uncle's house called Concrete Mathematics, apparently this is a undergraduate-level textbook and I am only in Highschool but I was still curious about the book.

In the 1.3 problem of the book, it wanted to solved recurrent relations without "clairvoyance".

According to the book, the recurrence can be simplified by adding +1 to both sides of the equation. But I don't understand how would +1 simplify the recurrence?

From:
\begin{align}
T_0 &= 0; \\
Tn &= 2T_{n-1} + 1 \\
\end{align}

To:

\begin{align}
T_0 + 1 &= 1; \\
T_n + 1 &= 2T_{n-1} + 2 \\
 &= T_{n-1} + 1 + T_{n-1} + 1 \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
U_{n} = T_{n-1}
\end{align}

Comment: The Issue is that you did not parse the textbook right. The last line $U_n=T_{n-1}$ is wrong. It should be $U_n=T_{n}+1$ , which will give $U_n=U_{n-1}+U_{n-1}=2U_{n-1}$ , then you get the Solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now define $V_n=T_n+1$ and your last equation becomes $$V_n=2V_{n-1}$$ with the solution $$V_n=2^nV_0$$
Adding $1$ makes the constant term disappear.

Comment: This answer is correct , though I do not see the value in it. When OP has the textbook which contains the same argument , then what more is given here to clarify the OP DOUBT ? Issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Prem It solves the problem, making it obvious in retrospect why the one was added. OP asked how adding one would simplify the recurrence, and this answer shows how.

Comment: The textbook has the same content , @Divide1918 , which OP should read instead. I am not saying the answer is wrong , I am saying it is correct & it is repeating what OP should read in the textbook.